# QGIS 3.32.0-2: Linking against qgis_core.lib

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, library

I am not able to link my dll with the current installation of QGIS 3.32.0-2 where it was possible with QGIS 3.30.3 (and lower).
Using: Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019, version Version 16.11.27

I updated my QGIS development installation to QGIS 3.32.0-2 with the osgeo4w-setup.exe program, option Advance Install from the website https://www.norbit.de.
When compiling and linking my windows dll, I get the following message:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: static struct QMetaObject const Qgis::staticMetaObject" (?staticMetaObject@Qgis@@2UQMetaObject@@B)  mfe_qgis_registration_only  d:\mooiman\home\examples\qt\qgis\qgis-plugins-registration-only\packages\moc_mfe_qgis_test.obj  1
```

When compiling/linking to QGIS 3.30.3 I used the libraries: qgis_analysis.lib, qgis_core.lib and qgis_gui.lib and with that libraries I had no problem.

Is the interface of the three libraries qgis_analysis.lib, qgis_core.lib and qgis_gui.lib used by QGIS 23.32.0-2 changed?
If not, what could be the problem?